# How to show an error message in java in a friendly way

Tags: java

I have a question as i am a beginner in java you may find it silly.

I am writing a method to read a file and when it does not exist an error just show up.

```
File f = new File(FILE_path);
            if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
                try {
                    //Do something
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    LOGGER.error("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("File does not exist or it cannot be read.");
            }
```

but other than the error that it shows the red error also shows up and then the program stops.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/project/file_path (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
```

Now my question is that is there anyway that the program does not freeze at this level and we show only the friendly message? or we cannot avoid that and this Exception error always show up even we use try and catch?

Comment: Have you read Oracle's tutorial: [Exceptions - Catching and Handling Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)?

Comment: Don't print the stack trace? Don't halt the program if the operation fails? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Why it is not clear?!! @DaveNewton

Comment: Because you show nothing that would "freeze". There's no context around your question: if you don't want to show the "unfriendly" stack trace then don't print it--*you* print it. Don't want it to freeze? No clue--there's nothing here that would "freeze", it would just exit. That's why it's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could always use joptionpanes:

```
File f = new File(FILE_path);
        if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
            try {
                //Do something
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Something went Wrong", "Title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                LOGGER.error("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("File does not exist or it cannot be read.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`is there anyway that the program does not freeze at this level and we show only the friendly message?`

Yes. Your IDE (eclipse or whatever) probably automatically placed `e.printStackTrace();` on the line after `catch (IOException e)` **but you don't need to do this.** And more experienced programmers would say it's completely unnecessary.

When you `catch` an exception in Java, you are getting control back after an Exception occurs. You can do absolutely anything after a `catch` that you can do at any other point in your program. You don't need to print the stack trace.

Sounds like you just want this:

```
`catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**Edit** if that is all you have in your `catch` block, then that is the only thing that will happen after an exception. Your program won't proceed out/down past the catch block.